# The search method is returning an extra result.

Tags: bug, status-completed

By default the [/search](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=search) method is supposed to return 30 results per page, but it's returning 31.  I only tested a few other values for `pagesize` but it looks like it always returns one extra result.

In case it makes a difference, I was using the `tagged` parameter to search by.  Here's an example:

http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/search?tagged=java&pagesize=1

Also, it doesn't seem to matter whether you provide an API key or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now fixed.